# Why is eval('"\x27"') == eval('"\\x27"')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very confused with python's eval():

I tried `eval('"\x27"') == eval('"\\x27"')` and it evaluates to `True`. Can somebody explain why this is the case? Both expressions evaluate to `"'"`. I understand why `eval('"\x27"')` does (the string evaluated has a single character, which is an escaped hexadecimal representing an apostrophe), but shouldn't `eval('"\\x27"')` be equal to `"\\x27"`?

Secondly, adding to the confusion, if I set the following variables,

```
s = "\x27"
t = "\\x27"
```

then `eval('s')` is again `"'"`, but `eval('t')` is `"\\x27"`. Why is that?

Comment: Reason #5 to avoid using `eval`: Even simple string literals become hard to read.

Comment: `eval('"\\\\x27"') equals "\\x27"` you need to double escape the backslash

Comment: One turns into eval("'") and the other turns into eval("\x27").  Eval itself will do a level of unescaping, so they will be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, `eval` "parses and evaluates the argument as a python expression". In other words, it's applying the same processing that is applied if you write `x = "foobar \n"` inside a program or the IDLE. In this example, `\n` gets turned into a newline-character (which, note, is not identical to the literal `\n`).

If you typed `x = "\x27"` into the IDLE, you'd get `x == "'"`. The `x27` is *escaped* because of the backslash and thus *changed* during *evaluation*. If you *escape the backslash*, then `x27` is *not* changed during evaluation. Instead, you simply get a string with a backslash followed by `x27`.

Now if you evaluated that string *again*, you only have one backslash left - seemingly escaping `x27`. Thus, it is changed to `'`.

Another way to look at this: `eval("\x27")` evaluates the argument *twice*, but it is only changed the first time, to `"'"`. `eval("\\x27")` also evaluates the argument twice, first to `\x27`, then to `"'"`.

---

Here's an easier example to demonstrate how this works:

```
>>> x = "\"foobar\""
>>> x == "foobar"
False
>>> x == "\"foobar\""
True
>>> x = eval(x) # changes value of x from "foobar" to just foobar. Still string though, thus still ""
>>> x == "foobar"
True
>>> x == "\"foobar\""
False
```

Look at it like this: The right hand side of `y = "2"` contains two components: the information that `y` should be of type string, expressed using the two `"`, and the *value* of that string, expressed by the character `2`. The separation of these two aspects is done during *evaluation* of the code you write. The string object itself never sees the `"` during initialization.

So in the above example, after the first line, we have `x` of type `str` with value `"foobar"`. If you evaluate that *again*, the `"` are interpreted this time not as part of the *value* of `x` but as the *type* of `x`. So `eval("\"foobar\"")` basically transforms the *string* `"foobar"` to `foobar`, which, if you want to use that using the language Python, you have to write as `"\"foobar\""` and `"foobar"`.

Comment: What is `y` in the code above? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Ups, sorry. Should be `x` too. Fixed.

Comment: @titiree I've updated the answer with more explaination.

Comment: When you say 'another way to look at this': `eval("\\x27")` will raise an error. Do you mean that `eval('"\\x27"')` first parses the string `"\\x27"`, then this gives `"\x27"` as a raw string and this is then evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

For `'"\x27"'` the backslash escape is expanded during parsing, so this is literally
`'"\'"'`. `'"\\x27"'` only strips the backslash, i.e. it is equal to `r'"\x27"'`.

A direct `eval()` on the string literals adds another iteration of special character expansion: In the first case, `\'` is a [valid escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) yielding `'`. The second case is the same as above.

When you use variable names, only one round of unescaping is performed when you assign the values. `eval('s')` simply expands to the value of `s` without further unescaping. If you want an emulation of the first case, you need to `eval(s)`, i.e. evaluate the value of the string referenced by `s`.